# c# RDCL Report Sum TimeSpan Format

Tags: c#, winforms, report, reportviewer, timespan

I'am using ReportViewer and RDCL report on windows form.
I have a field from sql

```
 select xxx,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),MAX(e.EventTime) - MIN(e.EventTime),108) as  total from xxx
```

and grouping by one field at RDCL report.

I have a field On group footer for group total 
field expression :

```
=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!total.Value)))
```

It displays like 4.10:30:00 (d.hh:mm:ss) if hours more than 24.
I want to show it like 106:30 (hhh:mm)  or 106.30

How can I do it from expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
=Math.Floor(Sum(TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!total.Value))/(36000000000)).ToString() + ":"+ Math.Round((Sum(TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!total.Value))/(600000000)) mod 60).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

With total seconds you can use this expression in row detail:

```
=IIf(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value < 86400,
    Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalSeconds.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"),
    Floor(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value / 86400) * 24 + (DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalSeconds.Value, "00:00:00")).Hour & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalSeconds.Value, "00:00:00"), "mm:ss")
)
```

For the group total:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value) < 86400,
    Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"),
    Floor(Sum(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value) / 86400) * 24 + (DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value), "00:00:00")).Hour & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TotalSeconds.Value), "00:00:00"), "mm:ss")
)
```

If you want your total group formatted as `HH:mm` simply modified format style as `mm` instead of `mm:ss`.